# Why do I get a header inclusion error on git submodule

Tags: c++, qt, git-submodules, qmake

I have taken another ones [library](https://github.com/ttlappalainen/NMEA2000/) and added it as a submodule to my repository.
I included the library like this.

```
#include "../NMEA2000/src/NMEA2000_CAN.h"
```

I compile using a qmake generated makefile. The header file and its includes are referred to in the .pro file as well.
I still get the following error:

```
In file included from ../NMEA2000/src/NMEA2000.h:50:0,
             from ../NMEA2000/src/NMEA2000_CAN.h:89,
             from MainWindow.cpp:15:
../NMEA2000/src/N2kCANMsg.h:26:10: fatal error: N2kMsg.h: file or directory not found
 #include <N2kMsg.h>
```

Apparently the file I included and the next one are being found but not another that is included there. If I change the file in question to `#include "N2kMsg.h"` instead. I will just run into the next one with a similar issue but pointing to another submodule.
I have a strong feeling that I am missing something about the way headers work. What am I doing wrong here? I would prefer not to touch the contents of the submodule.

Comment: `<file>` means look for the header in some "standard location or current directory". Some random subdirectory is not included in this definition. Your C++ compiler does not know anything about git or its submodules.

Comment: Probably here's is the error `#include "../NMEA2000/src/NMEA2000_CAN.h"` I suggest you change this to  `#include "NMEA2000_CAN.h"` and tell your compiler to add the location `../NMEA2000/src` as one of the places it looks for header files.

Comment: That would mean that the code in the library I want to use is misbehaving and I would better fork it?

Comment: Should be no need to fork. Sam is essentially saying the same thing John did.

Comment: That's essentially it. Thank you. :)
Added these two lines to my .pro file and it worked.
`INCLUDEPATH += ../NMEA2000/src \
../NMEA2000_socketCAN`
I have a different problem now but that seems like another topic for a different question.
`../NMEA2000/src/NMEA2000_CAN.h:163:15: error: cannot declare variable ‘serStream’ to be of abstract type ‘tSocketStream’
 tSocketStream serStream;`
Would you agree?